# java brain tutorial JAX-RS error setting up

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey

I tried the tutorial  of jax-rs by javabrains lesson 11. i created a maven project(jersey-quickstart-webapp), ran tomcat server. Jersey homepage works fine. But when i click jersey resource I get an error message:" The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." I haven't done anything yet to the initial code and i already got an error. Even tried downloading the exact version used in the video.. no luck

Using Apache Tomcat 8.5
Java 1.8
jersey version 3.0.0-M6

Comment: Do not run Tomcat 8.5 with jersey version 3.x. That won't work. Tomcat 10 works with Jersey 3, Tomcat 8.5 with Jersey 2.x.

Comment: I love you man.... it worked...